# PHP, Get all items of particular type in one array

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I have two tables Category and Dishes. Each Category has an id. And each dish belongs to a particular category. Now what I want is for all dishes belonging to a particular category to be grouped together. So All the Soups will be in the Soups Array [{Cabbage,Price,Description,...}, {Tomato,Price,Description,...}]. All the chicken in the chickens array and so forth. What I'm Currently doing is this:

```
    $query = "Select id from Category";
    $Id =  $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $Id->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idlist[] = $row["id"];
}





foreach ($idlist as $id){

    $query = "SELECT * from Dishes where Dishes.cat_id = '$id'";
    $Listings = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $Listings->fetch_assoc()) {
        $AllDishes[] = array(
           'id' => $row['id'],
           'Name' => $row['Name'],
           'Description' => $row['Description'],
           'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
           'Price' => $row['Price'],
           'ImagePath' => $row ['ImagePath']
          );
    }

}
```

But this results in all the dishes being grouped together. How do I separate the dishes based on their category? Also is this the right way to structure JSON Data?

Comment: what the field you used to save category name? Please tell

Comment: Your problem is in `$AllDishes[] = ` because you keep adding into `$AllDishes` variable for each category. You have to "change" storage variable for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.Use `JOIN` to do that in single query (best solution):-*

```
$query = "Select Dishes.*,Category.id as cat_id from Category LEFT JOIN Dishes on Dishes.cat_id = Category.id";
$Listings =  $mysqli->query($query);
$AllDishes = array();
while($row = $Listings->fetch_assoc()) {
    $AllDishes[$row['cat_id']][] = array(
       'id' => $row['id'],
       'Name' => $row['Name'],
       'Description' => $row['Description'],
       'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
       'Price' => $row['Price'],
       'ImagePath' => $row ['ImagePath']
      );
}
print_r($AllDishes);
```

***If you want to do in your coding way then:-***

*2.Distinguish them based on `id` of the category:-*

```
$query = "Select id from Category";//change column name
$Id =  $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $Id->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idlist[] = $row['id'];
}

foreach ($idlist as $id){
    $query = "SELECT * from Dishes where Dishes.cat_id = '$id'";
    $Listings = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $Listings->fetch_assoc()) {
        $AllDishes[$id][] = array(
           'id' => $row['id'],
           'Name' => $row['Name'],
           'Description' => $row['Description'],
           'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
           'Price' => $row['Price'],
           'ImagePath' => $row ['ImagePath']
          );
    }

}
```

*3.Distinguish them based on `name` of the category:-*

```
$query = "Select id,category_name from Category";//change column name
$Id =  $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $Id->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idlist[] = $row;
}

foreach ($idlist as $id){
    $id = $id['id'];
    $category_name = $id['category_name']; //change column-name
    $query = "SELECT * from Dishes where Dishes.cat_id = '$id'";
    $Listings = $mysqli->query($query);

    while($row = $Listings->fetch_assoc()) {
        $AllDishes[$category_name][] = array(
           'id' => $row['id'],
           'Name' => $row['Name'],
           'Description' => $row['Description'],
           'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
           'Price' => $row['Price'],
           'ImagePath' => $row ['ImagePath']
          );
    }

}
```

Note:- Please change the column-name in 3rd solution(as i don't know what column-name you have to store category names.)

Comment: Dare I ask for a third option which uses 1 SQL statement :)

Comment: Sorry - using 1 SQL statement with a join.

Comment: @NigelRen  added that.check once

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i thinks here will be your while loop for expected results

```
 $AllDishes = array();
 while($row = $Listings->fetch_assoc()) {
    $AllDishes[$row['Name']][] = array(
       'id' => $row['id'],
       'Name' => $row['Name'],
       'Description' => $row['Description'],
       'cat_id' => $row['cat_id'],
       'Price' => $row['Price'],
       'ImagePath' => $row ['ImagePath']
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use SQL joins instead of two separate SQL queries**

```
I hope the following may help you.



    $query = "SELECT * FROM Dishes INNER JOIN Category
                                   ON Dishes.id = Category.id ORDER BY Dishes.id";
    $res = $mysqli->query($query);      
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
   {
       $AllDishes[$$row['category_name']][] = array(
                                             'id' => $row['id'],
                                             'Name' => $row['Name'],
                                             'Description' => 
                                                  $row['Description'],
                                             'cat_id' => 
                                                  $row['cat_id'],
                                             'Price' => $row['Price'],
                                             'ImagePath' => 
                                                  $row['ImagePath']
                                           );//Array Close   
   }
```